# Takes date (only date not time) from the client and search in date (timestamp) column in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

In mysql I am using a date (timestamp) column so he stores date with time. but I am accepting ToDate and FromDate from user (this is only date without time). how will I search in date column ( date column stores date with time). and date (timestamp) column already exist in database, then I can't change column type.

Comment: Are you using hibernate in your application ?

Comment: yes.i am using hibernate.